# NDS Homebrew : can't compile in Visual Express 2008

Tags: homebrew, devkitpro, palib

I'm trying to get into NDS Homebrew,
and have installed devkitPro and PALib, and linked it with Visual Express 2008.

But When I try to compile the Hello World example code that is automatically generated when you start a new NDS project, I get the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: newtest, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Performing Makefile project actions
1>Linking...
1>c:/devkitpro/devkitarm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-eabi/lib/ds_arm9_crt0.o: In function `CIDLoop':
1>(.init+0x1c0): undefined reference to `__libnds_mpu_setup'
1>c:/devkitpro/devkitarm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-eabi/lib/ds_arm9_crt0.o: In function `CIDLoop':
1>(.init+0x210): undefined reference to `initSystem'
1>c:/devkitpro/devkitarm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-eabi/lib/ds_arm9_crt0.o: In function `CIDLoop':
1>(.init+0x21c): undefined reference to `__libnds_exit'
1>collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
1>make[1]: *** [/c/DSProjects/newtest/newtest/Release/newtest.elf] Error 1
1>make: *** [build] Error 2
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\DSProjects\newtest\newtest\Release\BuildLog.htm"
1>newtest - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

so obviously something is missing or wrong in devkitPro, but can't figure out exactly what and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PAlib is not supported, you broke devkitARM by installing it.

The only advice we have is to uninstall devkitARM completely then reinstall without PAlib. Once you've done that you should ask questions on the [devkitPro forums](http://devkitpro.org), the [gbadev forums](http://forum.gbadev.org), or, if you prefer realtime answers then there's always the [IRC channels](http://devkitpro.org/wiki/IRC)

Avoid PAlib, PAlib users and PAlib tutorials at all costs.

Comment: For those who don't know, @WintrMute is the creator and maintainer of devkirPro.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously something is missing or wrong from PAlib. devkitARM works perfectly fine for me. PAlib is old and very poorly written.